# I am getting enlarged logo image in HTML and CSS website in iphone safari browser. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, mobile-website

I am getting enlarged logo image in HTML and CSS website in iphone safari browser. As I have already set width and height in css using media queries but still I am getting this issue only in iphones not on android.

[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDRHI.jpg)

Please Visit this link to get the code and related files: https://github.com/abhijeetjain101/Portfolio-Website

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){

    .logo {
        max-height: 20%;
        max-width: 40%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some code!

Comment: You need to show us the relevant HTML and CSS because any answer without knowing how you are setting up the image will just be a guess. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that the screen dimensions are meant for your actual iPhone, sometimes they can be 1px off

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* Small phones line iPhone 5 SE */
@media screen and (max-width:374px) {
}

/* Regular phones like Iphone X + */
@media only screen and (min-width:375px) {
}

/* landscape mobile devices */
@media only screen and (min-width:480px){
}

/* tablet portrait */
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
}

/* tablet landscape */ 
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){
}

/*Small Monitor Screen */
@media only screen and (min-width:1280px){}

/* med Monitor Screen */
    @media only screen and (min-width:1440px){}


/* Large Monitor */
@media only screen and (min-width:1920px){}
```

This is kinda my starting point for any CSS script for Web Dev,
also ensure that if you're using, responsive attributes for image size that you dial it down or up based of screen needs when you mover to a new media query

Answer (score 0):

just give in style this code `img{width:100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

Just give **min & max width of image** or else use % instead px this might help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).